# send message to Node.js function with UIWebview

Tags: ios, node.js, uiwebview

There is a Node.js function  as `getdate(data1, date2)`.  I would like to send message to `getdate("hi","hello")` from UIWebview.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) might be able to help. Essentially it allows you to call server side JavaScript functions client side through RPC. In other words, it'll probably work for you.